# Limit Amount of Data Elements Held in Google Sheets Cells

Tags: google-sheets

There are various numbers of comma separated values in a Google Sheets column, how can I retain no more than the first 6 values in each cell & discard the rest?

Answer (score 1):

If the google sheet column is `column A`, you could try this formula:

```
=index(
ifna(
if(
len(A1:A)-len(substitute((A1:A), ",", ""))+1>=6,
regexextract(substitute(A1:A,",","§",6),"(.*)§"),
A1:A
)
)
)
```

where:

```
len(A1:A)-len(substitute((A1:A), ",", ""))+1>=6
```

checks that there are at least 6 commas in the cell and, if not, leaves its content unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for comma separated variables in column A (but less elegant then the first answer):

```
=arrayformula(lambda(exploded,lambda(maxcols,filter(exploded,sequence(1,maxcols)<=6))(
columns(exploded)))(
iferror(split(A:A,","))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I tried both formulas. Not knowing how to use them I inserted a row at the top of the sheet & placed the formula in the empty cell at the top of column E. The A's in the formula were replaced with E's, I got this popup error message:

"Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in E3."